# jQuery covert hover function to click function - switch?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a hover function (overlay) that works but I would prefer if it worked on click.
When clicked again it would revert to default. Then click another item for the same effect.
Tried to get it but having trouble. Would toggle be suitable here?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.trigger .orange-cell, .trigger .green-cell, .trigger .purple-cell, .trigger .white-cell, .trigger2 .orange-cell2, .trigger2 .green-cell2, .trigger2 .purple-cell2, .trigger2 .white-cell2').hover(function() {
        var colorClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        $("."+colorClass ).addClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
    },function() {var colorClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];;
        $("."+colorClass ).removeClass('z-relative');
        $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/LkaYOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var check = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cell').click(function() {
    console.log(check)
    if (check == true) {
      var colorClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
      $("." + colorClass).addClass('z-relative');
      $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
      check = false;
    } else {
      var colorClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];;
      $("." + colorClass).removeClass('z-relative');
      $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
      check = true;
    }

  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 46px;
}
ul {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical: top;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)
}
ul li {
  background: #fff;
  list-style: none;
}
body {
  background-color: wheat;
  font-family: Georgia, Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", serif;
}
#darkness {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: none;
  height: 150%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.z-relative {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.05);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
.cell {
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
/*ul li:nth-child()*/

.orange-cell,
.orange-cell2 {
  background: #ffc000;
}
.green-cell,
.green-cell2 {
  background: #92d050;
}
.purple-cell,
.purple-cell2 {
  background: #b3a2c7;
}
.white-cell,
.white-cell2 {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>DAY 1</h1>
<div id="darkness"></div>
<ul class="trigger">
  <li class="cell orange-cell">Home</li>
  <li class="cell green-cell">About</li>
  <li class="cell purple-cell">Contact</li>
  <li class="cell white-cell">Num</li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li class="cell orange-cell">Home</li>
  <li class="cell green-cell">About</li>
  <li class="cell purple-cell">Contact</li>
  <li class="cell white-cell">Num</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="cell orange-cell">Home</li>
  <li class="cell green-cell">About</li>
  <li class="cell purple-cell">Contact</li>
  <li class="cell white-cell">Num</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<h1>DAY 2</h1>
<ul class="trigger2">
  <li class="cell orange-cell2">HOVER ME</li>
  <li class="cell green-cell2">HOVER ME</li>
  <li class="cell purple-cell2">HOVER ME</li>
  <li class="cell white-cell2">HOVER ME</li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li class="cell orange-cell2 white-cell2" style="background:#ffc000;">Home</li>
  <li class="cell green-cell2">About</li>
  <li class="cell purple-cell2" style="background:#b3a2c7;">Contact</li>
  <li class="cell white-cell2" style="background:#FFF;">Num</li>
</ul>

<ul class="trigger2">
  <li class="cell purple-cell2 orange-cell2" style="background:#ffc000;">Home</li>
  <li class="cell purple-cell2 green-cell2" style="background:#92d050;">About</li>
  <li class="cell purple-cell2 white-cell2" style="background:#b3a2c7;">Contact</li>
  <li class="cell purple-cell2 white-cell2" style="background:#FFF;">Num</li>
</ul>

<ul class="trigger2">
  <li class="cell orange-cell2">Home</li>
  <li class="cell green-cell2">About</li>
  <li class="cell purple-cell2">Contact</li>
  <li class="cell white-cell2 purple-cell2" style="background:#FFF;">Num</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Do it like this. Have a check when true do the show on false remove

Comment: Thanks @guradio that seems to work nicely. 
I need to improve my skills set with jQuery. 
Out of interest is the true false console log to generic?

Comment: i am just logging the value of check.